# fiewViewById not finding my button (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded latest ADT from the main website and it came with Eclipse. So, I set everything up fine > Start new Android project. Set my settings, and the Activity to "Blank Activity", click finish.

Now, I go to the visual editor and add a button and some text. The problem is, is that "findViewById" is not detecting the button for some reason. Yes, I "Cleaned" the project and all that..

Here's the xml portion:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:text="@string/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my source code:

```
package com.example.tcp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button ibtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); // Error
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check in your R file whether there is id for button??

Comment: Do you have any xml errors?

Comment: clear the project or i think some error on ur xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually **save** the activity_main.xml?  View ID's are not accessible to the rest of the project until you save the layout you're working on.

I copied and pasted your code straight into a blank project and it worked fine after saving.

Answer (score 1):

Its just the basic error so clean your project and build again if its not work then restart eclipse and start once again it will display your button.In the same way you followed

don't even import R.java it will show you error..

so clean and build your project

Answer (score 1):

In your TextView you have

```
android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
```

Delete the plus so you have

```
android:layout_below="@id/button1"
```

Also it's better when you move the code of the textview below the code of the button. The Relative layout will position it where it's supposed to be anyway. But this way you don't link to an id that doesn't exist yet.

You declare a id with the + in the id. So in your case you declare it twice.

(Also for furure reference when you post something on StackOverflow with an error. Please mention the error in all cases. It makes finding the error and helping you a lot easier.)

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the R file and it was empty before I "ran" the project. After clicking "run" it added the id fields in the file. Seems to be working fine now. I guess it was actually a problem with the activity_main.xml not saving. Thanks again